# Intellij PyCharm Editor Error on Method Parameter Types

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am using Intellij PyCharm with Python 3.4 as the configured Python interpreter. PyCharm shows an error when specifying method parameter types. How can I reconcile this so that the editor does not complain? This is not a syntax error as the script runs fine. See below.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Your pycharm is obsolete. The above example works with pycharm 4.0.2.

Comment: I should mention that I am not using the pycharm editor per se, but the intellij pycharm 4.0 beta 140.58 community edition plugin as most of my modules are jvm-based.

Comment: Perhaps you should update that then? Both use the same codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am at the latest version of the plugin. Maybe this will be resolved in a future version.